Refused to set unsafe header "content-length" in Flutter Web
I am getting the error Refused to set unsafe header "content-length" on my console in flutter web. Currently i am using Get
class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;
  late SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;

  ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl, required this.sharedPreferences}) {
    baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
    timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.TOKEN) ?? "";
    _mainHeaders = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  void updateHeader(String token) {
    _mainHeaders = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };

    sharedPreferences.setString(AppConstants.TOKEN, token);

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('update header called for $token');
    }
  }

}

in my pubspec.yaml
  get: ^4.1.4
  http: ^0.13.3

and my flutter doctor -v
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.13.8 on channel stable at /Users/mac/FlutterDev/flutter
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/3.1.4/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/mac/FlutterDev/flutter. Consider
      adding /Users/mac/FlutterDev/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 6c4930c4ac (6 months ago), 2023-10-18 10:57:55 -0500
    • Engine revision 767d8c75e8
    • Dart version 3.1.4
    • DevTools version 2.25.0
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; however
      it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and
      upgrades.

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15E204a
    ✗ Unable to get list of installed Simulator runtimes.
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version unknown)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.84.0
    ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.4.1 23E224
      darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 123.0.6312.122

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

i do not understand why i am facing this issue
I have tried running it on chrome but in release mode
flutter run -d chrome --release
doesn't seem to fix the issue. I have also tired cleaning the project several times.
I do not want to completely upgrade flutter as it might affect all my other projects

Amazing that there is a 2 year old bug open for this https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/1500
